# Zoom Objek on center stage as3

Tags: zooming, center, stage

```
 buttonZoomIn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, zi_begin);
    function zi_begin(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
    if(map.scaleX < 6)
        {
        map.scaleX += 0.5;
        map.scaleY += 0.5;
        }
```

---

> I have images that can be enlarged ... but the image is enlarged from
>       the center of the image, instead of the center of the stage.... 
>       how to keep the image can be enlarged from the center stage not from
>       center image ?

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my simple code..

```
zoomin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_zoomin);
function f_zoomin(e:MouseEvent)
{
    zoom = 1;
    f_zoom();
}
zoomout.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_zoomout);
function f_zoomout(e:MouseEvent)
{
    zoom = -1;
    f_zoom();
}
function f_zoom()
{
    var coord:Point = map.globalToLocal(new Point(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2));
    map.scaleX += zoom;
    map.scaleY += zoom;
    map.x = ((2 * stage.stageWidth/2) - (2 * (coord.x * map.scaleX))) / 2;
    map.y = ((2 * stage.stageHeight/2) - (2 * (coord.y * map.scaleY))) / 2;
}
```

Btw your pic like my girlfriend.. LOL :D